# An unexpected result occurred while the file was importing its own global variables

Tags: python, import, global-variables

```
# main.py
var = 99
def importModule():
    import main
    print(main.var, end='>inside ')
    main.var = 0

importModule()
print(var, end='>outside ')
# out:99>inside 0>outside 0>inside 99>outside
```

Output is '99>inside 0>outside 0>inside 99>outside'
How did this happen??

Comment: when you run script then it has name `__main__` so it can import own code - and first it runs imported code (which doesn't import again `main` because Python remeber imported modules and doesn't load them again.

Comment: if you use `end=f' < {__name__} | ')` then you see `99 < main | 0 < main | 0 < __main__ | 99 < __main__ |`

Comment: `(main) main.var = 99 | (main) var = 0 | (__main__) main.var = 0 | (__main__) var = 99 | `